# In-App Review prompt is not visible after click "Not now" or "Cancel"

Tags: android, google-play, rating

I integrated the In-app Review provided by Google. I followed the documentation exactly as it is written. I hosted the app on Play store for testing, the prompt shows up the first time correctly. But when I click on `Not now` or `Cancel`, the prompt didn't show up again on that device.
I tried every possible way of re-installing or by clear cache but no luck.

Can anyone tell me is it the default behavior of In-App review prompt and when it will be visible next in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

To provide a great user experience, Google Play enforces a time-bound quota on how often a user can be shown the review dialog. Because of this quota, calling the launchReviewFlow method more than once during a short period of time (for example, less than a month) might not always display a dialog.

Because the quota is subject to change, it's important to apply your own logic and target the best possible moment to request a review. For example, you should not have a call-to-action option (such as a button) to trigger the API, as a user might have already hit their quota and the flow won’t be shown, presenting a broken experience to the user. For this use case, redirect the user to the Play Store instead.

Note: The specific value of the quota is an implementation detail, and it can be changed by Google Play without any notice.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#quotas)

Comment: Is there any particular or fixed time period after which it will display again?

Comment: Given the API design of not providing completion/result feedback, the quota mechanism is designed to help developers avoid the misuse of the API and over-triggering the review request. The exact quota is an implementation detail, and they are subject to change in the future.
Instead of trying to figure out the quota, the app should add its own logic (when/where is the best time to request for review) and rely on the API to launch the review when conditions apply.